# Saving variable data from jQuery to PHP and getting it after page reload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to PHP and trying to figure this out and still not understanding. I'm trying to take the value of a html text box in jQuery and turn it into a variable I can then store as a (variable or string?) and pull back again after a page refresh.

I want the user to hit a button that then executes the following:

```
$('.save').click(function () { 
    // pulls the value from the textarea
    var file = $('#subtext').val();
    // send to php to hold text
    $.ajax({
        url: '/mininote/system/data.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { textbox: file },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Saved data to php!');
            $(save).text('All changes saved.').show().delay(3000).fadeOut(800);
        }
    });

});
```

Then receives the post data and stores in the php until the user **reloads** the page where it pulls data (or checks if there is any) from the php like so and replaces the value of the textbox with the value from the php:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/mininote/system/data.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { textbox: file },
    success: function(data) {
        // add text back to text box
        $("#subtext").val(data);
    }
});
```

Basically what I'm looking for is below:-

1. a way to perform an ajax POST to insert the data grabbed from the textbox,
2. add to PHP
3. on a page reload use a GET request and replace textbox text with text from the PHP file.

What would I need to put into the PHP code? Or would it be easier to go in another direction? I've gotten this method to work in local storage. I also want browser compatibility for this work.

I don't need to set it up for a bunch of users. Any response that will increase my knowledge on this will help greatly.

**EDIT:** I'm really looking for something more server-side so it's usable across multiple platforms and devices.

Comment: Does the data matter server-side? Why not save yourself trouble and use _JavaScript's_ `sessionStorage`?

Comment: @PaulS. Why not use PHP's `session`?

Comment: @DummyCode If it is done client-side then no ajax would be required, you don't have to worry about delays or synchronous-ness, the code is shorter, less server overhead, etc etc.

Comment: It's more for personal use for now, I don't have the server capacity to expand it, and I have so many different computers and devices it would be nice to just save it that way(data on server). Plus at some point I plan to make it able to save the notes which is for a later day and another question.

Comment: @JoeyGallegos saving indefinitely with _JavaScript_ would be `localStorage`, but if you want it shared across devices then yes it needs something server side.

Comment: @Paul S Yeah, I really and looking for something that can be used to sync in real-time across multiple devices. I've done it with localStorage and it worked until I was on my phone and other computer. Thats why I'm looking to do something small on server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually **jquery-ajax** works like below:-

1. it takes request and
2. it gives response.

For Your requirement You also need to follow this steps. so for this , You

1. send **request** to PHP page then
2. send **response** from php page

so replace Your above **jquery-ajax** code part with below:-

```
$('.save').click(function () { 
    // pulls the value from the textarea
    var file = $('#subtext').val();
    // send to php to hold text
$.ajax({
    url: '/mininote/system/data.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { textbox: file },
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Saved data to php!');
        $('#subtext').val(data);
        $(save).text('All changes saved.').show().delay(3000).fadeOut(800);
    }
});

});
```

make sure in Your **data.php** page **textbox** value has made **echo** after inserting data to DB. This process would be something like below:-

**data.php**

```
<?php
     $textbox = $_POST["textbox"];
        /*
             perform Your DB inser part here
         */
      if(data inserted to db)
      {
            echo $textbox;
      }
?>
```

Hope this will help You.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following simple PHP script to accomplish your goal:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['textbox'])) {
   $_SESSION['textbox'] = $_POST['textbox'];
} else {
   echo $_SESSION['textbox'];
}
?>
```

Another option would be to use [HTTP Cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie). Just set the cookie with JavaScript using a [plugin](https://code.google.com/p/cookies/) or something simple such as, `document.cookie = "variable=value";` and access it in PHP with, `$_COOKIE["variable"]`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP code you could use a PHP session variable like so:

```
$_SESSION['saveMe'] = $saveMe;
```

Then get it later, even after a refresh, by using the session variable in php as you would normally use any variable.

For more info see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use a session, like a temporary cookie, like the following.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['sessionName'] = $sessionVar;
```

Then you can destroy the session with, `session_destroy();`

See more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Answer (score 0):

Why you send it to PHP ?
Just saving in client-side with cookie is better and access in PHP with $_COOKIE

#### Download jQuery.cookie from :

[carhartl/jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)
and do :

```
$('.save').click(function () { 
// save data from textarea to cookie
var data = $.trim($('#subtext').val());
$.cookie('TEXTAREA_VALUE', data);
});
```

and go to read by PHP :

```
<?php
echo $_COOKIE['TEXTAREA_VALUE'];
?>
```

and to remove :

```
$.removeCookie('TEXTAREA_VALUE', { path: '/' });
```

Okay friend !

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is mainly used for sending data without reloading the webpage - from client(js) to serverside(php) or from serverside(php) to client(js). Make sure that name-attribute is given in the textarea and that method is set to post in the form. If I understand your issue correctly you could do something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['subtext'])) {
    $_SESSION['subtext_value'] = $_POST['subtext'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['subtext_value'])) {
    $subtextValue = $_SESSION['subtext_value'];
}
else {
    $subtextValue = '';
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="/mininote/system/data.php" method="post">
<textarea id="subtext" name="subtext"><?php echo $subtextValue;?></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="ok" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```